# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime while converting specific date string to datetime

Tags: c#

I am getting error while converting string to datetime.

```
string dateStarted= "Wed Nov 27 2019 20:37:46 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)";
DateTime startedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateStarted);
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting with this code?

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: Method `Parse(string)` uses your current `Culture` information. Are you sure that the string you are trying to parse suits your current `Culture`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ParseExact` to convert string to datetime

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(
                    "Wed Nov 27 2019 20:37:46 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)",
                   "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)'",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```